# JQueryUI Datepicker directive malfunction after removing element using Angular's List.Splice()

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, angularjs-directive

The JQueryUI Datepicker malfunction when I remove an element using Angular list.splice($index,1) inside a ng-repeat statement.

After removing (using the del($index) function shown bellow), the calendar is shown but it starts picking the date for the next input, and the next input for the next one...

**Angular Controller:**

```
myApp.controller("CheckList", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
        $scope.items = [];

        ... // add/load function

        $scope.del = function (index) {
            $scope.items.splice(index, 1);

        };

}]);
```

**Angular Datepicker Directive:**

```
myApp.directive('datepicker', function ($timeout) {
       var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {

            $timeout(function () {
                element.datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                    changeYear: true

                });
            });
        }

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: linker,
            transclude: true
        }
});
```

**HTML**

```
  <div ng-controller="CheckList" id="divListItems" ng-cloak>
       <div ng-repeat="item in items" >
            <input type="text" datepicker id="CheckList-_{{$index}}_-ValidadeFinal"
                name="CheckList[{{$index}}].ValidadeFinal" ng-model="item.valfinal" />
      </div>
      <button type="button" ng-click="del($index)">Del</button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its caused by the ID being defined on HTML using the $index. When an element is removed, angular re-names and reset the ID of the fields (due the bind to $index) and malfunction the directive binding.

**Solution:**

Remove the ID definition from HTML Input and remove the "transclude=true" from the directive.

**HTML**

```
   <div ng-controller="CheckList" id="divListItems" ng-cloak>
       <div ng-repeat="item in items" >
            <input type="text" datepicker name="CheckList[{{$index}}].ValidadeFinal"
                 ng-model="item.valfinal" />
      </div>
      <button type="button" ng-click="del($index)">Del</button>
   </div>
```

**JQuery Datepicker Directive**

```
myApp.directive('datepicker', function ($timeout) {
   var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {

        $timeout(function () {
            element.datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                changeYear: true

            });
        });
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: linker
    }
});
```